# render vuejs component content in laravel blade

Tags: laravel, vue.js, components, laravel-blade

is there a way to render vuejs component into laravel blade templates, so when I open the source code of the page, instead of seeing

```
<example-component></example-component>
```

or

```
<example></example>
```

I want to see the real content of that component.

Comment: Blade is not in charge of that. Vue will replace this element with your actual html for you client-side. So your question is based on a wrong assumption.

Comment: To see original code , you just go to resource 'resources\assets\js\components' there you can see ExampleComponent

Comment: @ThomasMoors yes I know that, that's why I'm asking if there is a way to achieve it.

Comment: What you're asking for is called [server side rendering](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/ssr.html), or just SSR.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to see them from 'view page source', once open the page, if you can see your vue component displays there, right click on it, use 'inspect'.